# Picture and Paragraph in Metapost

Tags: diagrams, context, paragraphs, metapost

How to insert a paragraph in Metapost and a drawing below that? This has to be done within a single Metapost block, (i.e) within a single `\startMPcode` and `\stopMPcode` block

Sample image :

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you did not specify your exact problem, nor any example code I can
just blindly guess where the problem is. I assume you want to use `\framed`
within `textext`. You have to use `align=normal` to create a `vbox`. You can as well simply use a `\vbox` if you don't need the features the `\framed` command provides.

Here is a complete example. As “drawing” I simply used a black square.

```
\startbuffer
  \input hawking
\stopbuffer

\starttext
  \startMPcode
    draw textext.top("\framed[align=normal]{\getbuffer}");
    fill fullsquare
      xyscaled (TextWidth, 1cm) shifted (0, -5mm);
  \stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

[image: result]